# How to select a view from a viewmodel if different views share the same viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Since some of my views have similar functions, I want to be able to share the same viewmodel with each view. My idea is to pass a token to the viewmodel's constructor, but this will lead to many `if` and `else` statements in my code. Any ideas that I can avoid too many if else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inheritance and datatemplate.  Create a base class viewmodel and virtual functions.  Override them with different functionality.  Then use datatemplate to load the different views according to the view model you need.